# Use addScriptOptions for multiple modules on same page

Tags: development, custom-module, jdocument

I am passing some params to JS in my custom module using the addScriptOptions provided by Joomla:

```
$document->addScriptOptions("mod_mymodule", $params));
```

This works fine, as long as there is only 1 instance of the same module on 1 page. But how to make it work for multiple modules on the same page?

I would think to pass 1 object like so:

```
$document->addScriptOptions("mod_mymodule", (object)array($params => $module->id)));
```

In my JavaScript file I can log the object:

```
console.log(Joomla.getOptions('mod_mymodule'));

// Output:
  {
  105: {...}
  }
```

So the problem is that **only the first module is passed in the object**. I need every module to be passed in the object before it is passed to my JS file, so I can loop over the object to create desired script for each module.

**Addition:**
I think I'm getting closer, but still not working:

```
$currentOptions = $document->getScriptOptions('mod_mymodule');
if ($currentOptions) :
    $currentOptions->{$module->id}->{$params};
else :
    $document->addScriptOptions("mod_mymodule", (object)array($module->id => $params));
endif ;
```

I think the logic is there, or not? Syntax error? I'm not sure..

Any insights? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple code review:

You don't need the condition block because `getScriptOptions()` always returns an array.

[`getScriptOptions()` documentation](https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/Joomla.CMS.Document.Document.html#method_getScriptOptions)

If you want to declare the variable `$configs`...

```
$configs = $document->getScriptOptions('mod_mymodule');
$configs[$module->id] = $params;
$document->addScriptOptions("mod_mymodule", $configs);
```

If you don't want to declare the variable...

```
$document->addScriptOptions(
    "mod_mymodule",
    array_replace(
        $document->getScriptOptions('mod_mymodule'),
        [$module->id => $params]
    )
);
```

Both snippets execute the same behaviour, here's what is happening...

- If the returned array from `getScriptOptions()` already contains a key which matches the `$module->id` value, then the element will be overwritten.
- If the key does not yet exist in the array, then the element will merely be added to the array.

Comment: Hah. Even better. Thanks for pointing that out! :)

Answer (score 1):

Okay.. Found the solution. Here we go:

```
$configs = $document->getScriptOptions('mod_mymodule');

if ($configs) :
    $configs[$module->id] = $params;
else :
    $configs = array($module->id => $params);
endif ;

$document->addScriptOptions("mod_mymodule", $configs);
```

The logic wasn't that hard. I'm still pretty new at php and Joomla! development.

Hopefully it will be of some use to someone else. Cheers!